# Get column data from each line of output from ls -l

Tags: bash, multidimensional-array

I have a script to identify flash files in memory to be copied or passed to a program such as vlc for playback.

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=($(ps aux | grep flash | grep -v grep | grep -v bin/flash))
cd "/proc/${pid[1]}/fd"
file=($(echo `ls -l  | grep /tmp/`))
file="${file[8]}"
echo "$file"
```

This works well but I want it to return each matching file, as it is it only returns the first one.

I would normally do something like a multidimensional array but bash doesn't have those and even if it did I wouldn't know the syntax.

How do I split the output by line and then echo the `[8]` value from each?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Then my problem becomes "How to create an array of filenames of symlinks pointing to /tmp/ folder" - which is probably a much more complicated problem. But since we're in the /proc/ directories all file names will be simple integers so we can parse `ls` without much trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `awk` for this:

```
files=$(ls -l|awk -F"-> " '/\/tmp/{print $2}')
```

This is not failsafe at all (parsing the output of  `ls` generally isn't).

A safer approach if your `find` supports it would be:

```
files=$(find . -type l -printf "%l\n")
```

(Still not safe if you have spaces in the filename.)

This should be pretty robust and give you a bash [array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) to boot:

```
IFS=$'\n' files=($(find . -type l -printf "%l\n"|grep /tmp))
```

(still fails with filenames that contain `\n`.)

Comment: Nice answers, I'm using a loop with readlink, it doesn't allow me to pipe the output to another command properly (Because it's not `cd`ing before `echo`ing) but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This handles multiple lines of output from `ps`, too. Maybe you can have more than one Flash process?

```
#!/bin/sh
for pid in $(ps aux | awk '/[f]lash/ && !/bin\/[f]lash/{print $1}); do
    for file in /proc/$pid/fd/*; do
        case $(readlink "$file") in
            /tmp/*) echo "$file" ;;
         esac
    done
done
```